# Cannot find starting value for variable

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to numerically solve and plot two coupled first-order differential equations using ParametricNDSolve over the region $(0,a)$ where $a$ is the parameter.

```
qpSol = ParametricNDSolve[
   {D[q[t], t] == q[t] - q[t]^2 + p[t]*q[t]^2 - 2*p[t]*q[t], 
    D[p[t], t] == -p[t] + p[t]^2 - q[t]*p[t]^2 + 2*q[t]*p[t], 
    p[a] == 0, q[0] == 1}, 
    {q, p}, {t, 0, a}, a]

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{p[a] /. qpSol, q[a] /. qpSol}], 
    {t, 0, a}], {a, 0.1, 100}]
```

However, when I run this code, I run into the error:

```
ParametricNDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable q.
```

Which makes no sense, since I clearly provide the initial condition for q in the fourth line, $q[0]==1$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `t` somewhere in whatever you are plotting?

Comment: Are you sure the parameter can be for the boundary conditions only? I thought parameter has to be in the ODE itself. But this is not what you have. Do you know of an example where the parameter was used for the end of the time limit and not in the ODE?

Comment: @Nasser I'm actually not sure if that would work or not. I see no reason why it shouldn't, but I haven't seen explicit examples of that.